# Laravel Unique Validation with condition face some issue

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm trying to make `child_date_of_birth` as unique. When I make `child_date_of_birth` unique. i face  some issue which is `array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given`. How i can solve this issue?

```
  $unique=['child_birth_certificate_no' => 'required|unique:child,child_birth_certificate_no,centre_id',] ; //unique validate

        //Validate inputs

        $input= Input::only('child_birth_certificate_no'); 

        $validator = Validator::make($input, $unique);

        return $to_validate;
}
```

The error is

[image]

Comment: unique:table_name,column_name

Comment: I should include my table name is it?

Comment: just `unique:table_name` is ok, you need to tell it which table

Comment: I still face the same issue

Comment: which line of code cause this error ? it says line 92. what's that code in that line

Comment: I already edit my code. Can you check my code is correct or not?

Comment: First, please don't tag the question with jQuery Validate when it has nothing to do with this plugin.  Edited.   Secondly, please don't post a screenshot of an error message when you can copy and paste the text of the error message.  Obviously, the search engine built into this site only works on text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [manually-creating-validators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#manually-creating-validators)

You parameters' order is wrong. Change them like this:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($input, $unique);
```

Comment: Can you help to check my code correct or wrong? I already edited

Comment: @NavanithaMoorthy it looks correct. you can test it.

Comment: but why when i put same ```child_birth_certificate_no``` it's still saving? I want to give like alert or smthg else. Can you gimme id?

Comment: @NavanithaMoorthy It means that it cannot found the same `child_birth_certificate_no` value in table `child`

Comment: ``` $this->validate($request,array(
            'child_birth_certificate_no' =>'required|unique:child,child_birth_certificate_no,centre_id',
        ));``` 
Can i knw about this validation?